# Contract doesn't work

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I am stuck on a problem with `System.Diagnostics.Contracts`.

If I use `Contract.Requires(condition)`, then all works as expected.
But I need a custom Exception, so I tried `Contract.Requires<ToShortException>(condition)`.

When `condition` was false, I expected a `ToShortException` but I got nothing. In the debugger I can see, that this line was ignored.

`ToShortException` is a public class which implements `Exception` and has 3 public constructors.

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

The Exception class:

```
public class ToShortException : Exception
{
    public ToShortException()
    {
    }

    public ToShortException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public ToShortException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {

    }
}
```

Method of a class:

```
    public IDictionary<string, string> getIncident(string name)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)); //works fine
        Contract.Requires<ToShortException>(name.Length == 7); //got not checked

        return _original.getIncident(name);
    }
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Is your question possibly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991647/throwing-an-exception-vs-contract-requirest)?

Comment: I think not, but `if-then-throw` was a alternative. But the whole project works fine with `Contracts` (except for this line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. "Project Settings -> Code Contracts -> Assembly Mode" has to be "Standard Contract Requires".

[image]

The default-value was "Custom Parameter Validation".